# how to set file on cron job on go daddy cpanel

Tags: cron

i am facing a problem related to cron job.i have to set two files in  cron job on go daddy server. and i have already set this but permission denied error is coming. how i can solve this.
Please help me to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: You best chances are asking the godaddy support.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion